# Can I tell if I'm being attracted by a gravitational field by checking if my time is dilated relative to an observer?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity

Due to the equivalence principle of GR, we know that gravity and acceleration are indistinguishable from each other. We also know that a gravitational field causes time dilation, but accelaration does not.

IF I were in a ship, could I know whether it is accelerating upwards/being gravitationally attracted by comparing my proper time to that of an external observer? If mine runs slower, that means that it is gravitational time dilation. What am I missing here?

Comment: First paragraph is incorrect. You state what the equivalence principle is and then immediately contradict it!

Comment: See https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/137387/doppler-shift-for-a-uniformly-accelerating-observer

Comment: Ie, you can never tell the difference

Answer (score 0):

> We also know that a gravitational field causes time dilation, **but accelaration does not.**

In the 'elevator pulled upward in outer space with constant acceleration' thought experiment, a photon emitted from some process at the bottom of the elevator is received at the top with a longer wavelength than a photon emitted by the same process at the top.

This *must* be the case since, during the time of flight from bottom to top, the receiver speed, relative to the emitter at the time of emission, has increased.

Put another way, a clock at the top of the elevator observes relatively stationary clocks below to run slower with a linear dependence on the distance below.

But this is precisely the result if the elevator were at rest in a (uniform) gravitational field.